# Android notifications event

Tags: android, events, callback, notifications

I need to detect that user open notifications window during playing our Game (to pause the game for example). I thought that onPause / onResume overrides will be called but it doesn't. I've searched through the internet and it seems that nobody will solve it...

Can you help me?

Thanks. Jiri

Comment: Are you using a framework for your game?

Comment: @Eucar It is cocos2d game so the activity is inherited from Cocos2dxActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found the solution. It is ok to use onWindowFocusChanged() override. this is called when app lost focus even in that case of opening notification center.